Is there any full manuscript(or printed edition) of Sanatkumar Samhita which is a part of the Samhita version of Skanda Puran available?
In the Samhita version of Skanda Puran, we have the Sanatkumar Samhita, just to clarify, it is not the Panchratra Sanatkumar Samhita, can anyone specify in which library, a full manuscript of the Sanatkumar Samhita can be found? It is available in bits and pieces,in the form of Shiva-tatwa-sudha-nidhi, Shri-Ram-Stavaraj etc. but not complied properly as a whole book.
What is the correspondence between Khandas and Samhitas in the Skanda Purana?
In the above link, it is mentioned that the Manuscript of Sanatkumar Samhita is extant, so where can we find that?

Is this what you are looking for? Kumar Samhita

I don't think so because the Colophon doesn't mention Skanda Puran or something as Sanat Kumar Samhita. Also, it seems like a Tantrik text, instead.
